# WPF: why my Combobox SelectionChanged event is fired before my chart control created

Tags: wpf, charts, combobox

So i have application and another sub form:

```
public partial class SubForm: MetroWindow...
```

And here is how i am open my `Sub form` from my main `form`:

```
SubForm subForm = new SubForm();
subForm.ShowDialog();
```

Inside my `Sub form` i have this `chart` control:

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart
    x:Name="chart" />
```

And `Combobox`:

```
<ComboBox
    Name="cbInterfaces" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(my:MyClass.MachineInterfaces)}"
    SelectedIndex="0"
    SelectionChanged="cbInterfaces_SelectionChanged"/>
```

So i notice that after the `Sub form` oped right after `InitializeComponent` method, the code is go into my `Combobox` `SelectionChanged` event and my `chart` control is still `null` and not created yet.
So i cannot use it until use again my `Combobox` and change selection again (in this case my `chart` not null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just return from the event handler immediately if the window or the `RadCartesianChart` haven't yet been initialized or loaded:

```
private void cbInterfaces_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsLoaded || chart == null || !chart.IsLoaded)
        return; //do nothing

    //your code...
}
```

> Yes but the problem is that after this form created and opened i want to see my snuff immediately in my chat instead of change my combobox selection again ...

Set the `SelectedIndex` property programmatically after the call to the `InitializeComponent()` method then:

```
public partial class SubForm : Window
{
    public SubForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cbInterfaces.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void cbInterfaces_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

---

```
<ComboBox
    Name="cbInterfaces" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(local:MyClass.MachineInterfaces)}"
    SelectionChanged="cbInterfaces_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Comment: Yes but the problem is that after this form created and opened i want to see my snuff immediately in my chat instead of change my combobox selection again, in my main form i have the same controllers (combobox and chat) and after this form created my chart is not null, why i have this differences ?

Comment: Set the SelectedIndex property programmatically after the call to the InitializeComponent() method then. See my edited answer.