# WPF: add chart control inside Combobox

Tags: wpf, templates, combobox, telerik

So i have this model:

```
public class MachineNetworkAdapter
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string IpAddress { get; set; }
  public static List<MachineNetworkAdapter> MachineAdapters;
}
```

So each mechine adapter have this members.

So i have this `Combobox` that show all my  Machine Adapters:

```
<ComboBox
    Name="cbAdapterss" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MachineAdapters}"
    SelectionChanged="cbInterfaces_SelectionChanged"/>
```

So in this case i can see all my machine adapters with this properties.

Now i want to see also my adapters `Rate` in `MBit/sec` so i added this members:

```
  public Series { get; set; }
  public double Rate { get; set; }
```

the member `Rate` is `MBit/sec` and the value is changing every 1 sec.
the `series` is for the chart in order to put into the values.

So i added template with `chart`and now this is my `Combobox`:

```
<ComboBox
    Name="cbAdapters" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MachineAdapters}"
    SelectionChanged="cbInterfaces_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerik:RadCartesianChart
                x:Name="chartTemplate"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

So now all i can see in my `Combobox` is an empty `chart` without the other properties.
So my question is how can i populate my `chart` and also see the other properties (Name, IPAddress).

Comment: Did you solve your last issue?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42833185/wpf-why-my-combobox-selectionchanged-event-is-fired-before-my-chart-control-cre/42833268?noredirect=1#comment72776081_42833268

Comment: Oh yes sorry for this, just saw it now

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the other properties?

Comment: Inside my combobox, after add this chartTemplate i can see now only an empty chart